# Trying to create a horizontal layout with Twitter API which includes media entities?

Tags: javascript, php, image, api, twitter

After a little help and guidance on this as I'm fairly new to javascript/php and can't seem to figure out my problem, just dance around it.

Anyway...

My goal is to create a horizontal scrolling twitter feed (left to right) with each tweet consisting of the photo/video/gif above with the tweet text below it.

I've managed to use elements of twitter API to pull in the right information/including photos (haven't figured out videos/gifs yet) and using css to place it above its corresponding tweet. Fabulous.

Thing is, through retrieving any media/photo content of a tweet it doesn't nest itself within the div('singular_wrap_open') I've created to hold the image/tweet, instead sits above it in its own image tag which means I then can't style everything together to display inline, and therefore display horizontally. At the moment I have it but the tweets are displaying vertically.

If I 'display: inline-block' the photo and also the div('singular_wrap_open') I can get the tweets and photo to display horizontally next to each other but obviously the photos are no longer above the tweets as I would like..

Thus my dilemmas are as so:

1.Any advice on how I can get the twitter image to display above the tweet in a div. while also getting each tweet/photo combo to display horizontally aligned next to the others?

2. Can anyone point me in the direction of how I manage to get videos/gifs working through API? Currently it looks like its pulling through the data but is displaying a frame as an image? Suspecting its something to do with the img tag I have it wrapped in?
3. Not all tweets will have a media/photo element tweeted with them, and will simply be a text tweet on occasion. What I'd like to do is for any tweet that has no media/photo attached to instead show a placeholder image. Is this something achievable?

Things to note:
- I'm building upon the base code from: https://github.com/andrewbiggart/latest-tweets-php-o-auth/

Here are some snippets of the code. Apologies for any beginners errors!!

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZqzoj

```
    // Function parameters.
    $twitter_user_id,
    $cache_file          = './tweets.txt',  // Change this to the path of your cache file. (Default : ./tweets.txt)
    $tweets_to_display   = 6,               // Number of tweets you would like to display. (Default : 5)
    $ignore_replies      = false,           // Ignore replies from the timeline. (Default : false)
    $include_rts         = true,           // Include retweets. (Default : false)
    $include_extended_entities   = true,
    $truncated           = false,
    $tweet_mode          = 'extended',
    $singular_wrap_open  = '<div class="singular_wrap_open">',
    $singular_wrap_close = '</div>',
    $twitter_wrap_open   = '<ul class="home-tweets-ul">',
    $twitter_wrap_close  = '</ul>',
    $tweet_wrap_open     = '<li><p class="home-tweet-tweet">',
    $meta_wrap_open      = '<span class="home-tweet-date">',
    $meta_wrap_close     = '</span>',
    $tweet_wrap_close    = '</p></li>',
    $favourite_count     = true,
    $retweet_count       = true,
    $date_format         = 'M jS g:i A',    // Date formatting. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
    $twitter_style_dates = true){           // Twitter style days. [about an hour ago] (Default : true)


// GET connection
if($connection){
            $get_tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?tweet_mode=extended&screen_name=".$twitter_user_id."&count=".$tweets_to_display."&include_rts=".$include_rts."&exclude_replies=".$ignore_replies."&tweet_mode=extended");
            // Get the latest tweets from Twitter

            // Error check: Make sure there is at least one item.
            if (count($get_tweets)) {

                // Define tweet_count as zero
                $tweet_count = 0;

                // Start output buffering.
                ob_start();

                // Open the twitter wrapping element.
                $twitter_html = $twitter_wrap_open;

                // Iterate over tweets.
                foreach($get_tweets as $tweet) {
                        $tweet_found = true;
                        $retweeted = true;
                        if (isset($tweet->retweeted_status)) {
                            $retweeted = $tweet->user;
                            $tweet = $tweet->retweeted_status;
                        }
                        $media_url = $tweet->extended_entities->media[0]->media_url;
                            if($media_url) {
                            $item =     "<img class='twitter_photo' src='{$media_url}'/>";
                            $twitter_html .= $item;
                            }


                        $tweet_mode = 'extended';
                        $retweeted_status = full_text;
                        $extended_entities = true;
                        $favorite_count = true;
                        $retweet_count = true;
                        $tweet_count++;
                        $tweet_desc = $tweet->full_text;
                        // Add hyperlink html tags to any urls, twitter ids or hashtags in the tweet.
                        $tweet_desc = preg_replace("/((http)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i", "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $tweet_desc );
                        $tweet_desc = preg_replace("/[@]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/", "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $tweet_desc );
                        $tweet_desc = preg_replace("/[#]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/", "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23\\1\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $tweet_desc );



// Render the tweet.
                        $twitter_html .= $singular_wrap_open.$meta_wrap_open.'<a href="http://twitter.com/'.$twitter_user_id.'/status/'.$tweet_id.'">'.$display_time.'</a>'.$meta_wrap_close.$tweet_wrap_open.html_entity_decode($tweet_desc).$tweet_wrap_close.$singular_wrap_close;



// CSS
.home-tweets-ul {
list-style:none;
text-align: center;
position:relative;
padding: 80px 0px;
justify-content: center;}

ul.home-tweets-ul li {
margin: 0 10px;}

.home-tweets-ul li a {
color: #63b7e5;}

.home-tweets ul li img {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;}

p.home-tweet-tweet{
padding:20px;}

.home-tweet-date {
background-color: #396aa5;
max-width: 250px;
height: 2rem;
display:block;
text-align: center;
padding-top:1rem;}

.home-tweet-date a {
color:#FFF;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;}

.singular_wrap_open {
vertical-align:top;
background-color: #417abd;
margin: 0px;
max-width: 250px;
text-align: left;
list-style:none;
width: 250px;}

img.twitter_photo {
max-width: 250px;
display:block;
position:relative;
}

.tweet_block {
width: 250px;
margin: 0px 20px;}
```

Comment: Could you put together a codepen with your HTML and CSS? It's quite difficult to see the problem in it's current form as you have HTML mixed in with PHP. It's a pain on the eyes and will likely reduce your response rate.

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding! I'm not too sure on what you mean or how I would extract the html currently from the php as I have it rendering the tweet? Also it is currently authenticating through a local file to pull in the tweets. I have added it to codepen here just so the code is easier to see, hope this helps?: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZqzoj

Comment: The problem is if others want to reproduce what you're seeing to help you find a solution they're going to have great difficulty.

Comment: I understand and thank you for your help so far. How would you recommend I deconstruct it into a better format? I'm a newbie so thanks for your patience :)